# Update ALL changes in a table

Tags: vb.net

Tableadapter update configuration for VS2017

Dear members,
Sorry, I have to harass you again with a VB.net SQL problem in VS2017.
I searched the internet for many days now, but did not find a solution for my problem. All the examples are or C and outdated.

The situation is as follows:
• Created a Tabteadapter update method to change fiels in a DB.
• Modified a field in all  rows (RENUM field Oserial).
• Tried  with Tableadapter to update the changes in the DB.
• Always an error is generated, except if the Oserial field is set to the value of another field or  literal (set Oserial = PID)  in this case  the DB has  realy changed but not with the right values.

I do not understand how to configurea  Update method that
Update all changes  in the tabletwithout setting new values.
Hopefully someone can help me out or tell me where to find a sample 
source code.

My code:-----------------------

```
Public parmPID As String = "159"

Public Sub Renum()
    Dim n As Integer = 0

    Dim DS As New Pr2DataSet1()
    Dim TA As New Pr2DataSet1TableAdapters.OBjectsTableAdapter()

    TA.OBjectsFillByPIDOserial(DS.OBjects, parmPID)
    Try
        For Each dr As DataRow In DS.Tables(0).Rows
            n = n + 1
            DS.Tables(0).Rows(n - 1).Item   ("Oserial") = n 
       Next

        TA.ObjectsUpdateOserial(parmPID)
        TA.Connection.Close()

    Catch x As Exception
        Labelbox.Text = x.ToString
    End Try
End Sub
```

DB design: ---------------------------

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OBjects] (
[PID]          INT   NOT NULL,
[OID]  INT   IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT  ULL,
[Oserial]      INT    NOT NULL,
```

SQl Query 1  :----------------------

```sql
UPDATE [dbo].[OBjects] 
set Oserial= PID
WHERE (PID = @parmPID)
```

this works OK but with changed PID vlues

SQl Query 2  :----------------------

```sql
UPDATE [dbo].[OBjects] 
set Oserial 
WHERE (PID = @parmPID)
```

ERROR:  :----------------------

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near
>   the keyword 'WHERE'.  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,

Answer (score 0):

Of course this doesn't work:

```sql
UPDATE [dbo].[OBjects] 
set Oserial 
WHERE (PID = @parmPID)
```

You're not specifying what to set `Oserial` to.  You have to specify a value to set that column to, just as you're doing in the SQL that you say does work.  You can specify a literal value, an expression or a parameter but you have to specify something that evaluates to the value you want to set the column to.

The fact is, though, that you're just doing the saving wrong.  Your table adapter already has a method that will save all the changes for you: the `Update` method.  You don't need anything else.  Just change this:

```
TA.ObjectsUpdateOserial(parmPID)
```

to this:

```
TA.Update(DS.OBjects)
```

and you're good to go.

The way a table adapter works is that it contains one or more queries, i.e. `SELECT` statements, and three actions statements, i.e. one each of `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements.

By default, the table adapter has `Fill`, `GetData` and `Update` methods.  You can call `Fill` or `GetData` to execute the default query, which is basically a `SELECT *` and should be left that way.  The `Fill` method will populate an existing `DataTable` while the `GetData` method will create a new `DataTable` and populate it.  You normally use `Fill` for a `DataTable` in a `DataSet` and `GetData` for a lone `DataTable`.

Once you have made any changes you want to make, you call `Update` and those changes will be saved.  `Update` executes the `InsertCommand` for all `DataRows` with a `RowState` of `Added`, the `UpdateCommand` for `Modified` rows and the `DeleteCommand` for `Deleted` rows.

If you want to add another query, e.g. to filter by a specific column, then you can do that in the designer.  Doing so will add two new methods equivalent to `Fill` and `GetData` but executing your new query rather than the default query.  You should use the provided `FillBy` and `GetDataBy` prefixes for those methods and name them after the column(s) in the filter.  In your case, if you're filtering by `PID` then those methods should be named `FillByPID` and `GetDataByPID`.

Whether you use those methods to populate a `DataTable` or the defaults, you still use `Update` to save all the changes in a `DataTable`.  If you want to see the SQL used in those action commands, select your table adapter in the `DataSet` designer and take a look at the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` in the Properties window.

Comment: yOU JUST MADE MY DAY!